# Angular6: reuploading same Image wont trigger upload method

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, upload, angular6

I want to upload an image to my angular6 Website and display it, which works perfectly fine with this code.

Html:

```
<img #signatureImage src="{{imageSrc}}">
<input hidden type="file" #file (change)="uploadImage($event)"/>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('signatureImage') img: ElementRef;

...

uploadImage(input) {
  if (input.target.files && input.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      this.imageSrc = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

After removing the image (`imageSrc = ''`) and reuploading the same file does not trigger the `(change)="uploadImage($event)"`, since the file has no "changed" values or something like that. The result is that when selecting the same file nothing happens.

So is there an alternative in Angular6, which calls my method regardless of choosing the same image twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found a simple solution.

```
<input hidden type="file" #file
 (change)="uploadImage($event); file.value = ''">
```

Right after choosing an image, you can just reset the path, the image was choosen from, so when reuploading the same image again the `(change)` method will still get triggered. I just had to add `file.value = ''`.

Comment: a small note: internet explorer will call the change method after the value is set to '' so the corrosponding method (in this case the uploadImage function) needs to be able to catch that